# How to select item from listview in selectedindexchanged event?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    img1 = Image.FromFile(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text);
    pictureBox1.Image = img1;
}
```

I have 10 items in the listView.

If I'm using it like it is now with `SelectedItems[0].Text`, when I select any item, the first time it's working fine, but then when I'm selecting another item, it's throwing this error :

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.
> Parameter name: index'

Comment: Everything is in my answer to your previous question.

Comment: @NineBerry `e.Item`  have a debug error...

Comment: Use the SelectionItemChanged event, not the SelectedIndexChanged event. Then you can access the item directly from the event.

Comment: @NineBerry right i just saw it in the previous question, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

When the event is raised, the details of the item are passed into the event, via 'e'.  The type of e will be a ***ListViewItem***, therefore you can use ***e.Item.Text*** to access the text of the selected item.

The reason you may be seeing the exception is because I suspect as the selected index changes, it may be unselecting the selected item before it selects the new one, therefore, there isn't an item at Index 0 in this case.  You could get around this by wrapping your existing code in an "IF" check like so:

```
if (listView1.SelectedItems[0] is not null) 
{
    //DO PROCESSING HERE
}
```